# Read/Write text file in C programming

Tags: c, file, text

I need to write something into a txt file and read the contents, then print them on the screen.
Below is the code I have written, it can create and write contents into file correctly, but it cannot read from the file and print correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    char filename[20]={"c:\\test.txt"};
    FILE *inFile;
    char c;
    inFile=fopen(filename,"w+");

    if(inFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("An error occoured!");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        fputc(c,inFile);
    fputc('\0',inFile);

    while((c=fgetc(inFile))!=EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

Would someone tell me what's wrong with this program, especially the last two lines.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you learning K&R C in 2011? There's no more implicit `int` type. The `main` function needs a return type. And it should return something.

Comment: For reference, the Windows API can deal with forward slashes as well as backslashes as directory separators.  I generally prefer forward slashes, mostly because i don't have to worry about escaping them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add

```
fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

before

```
while ((c=fgetc(inFile)) != EOF)
     putchar(c);
```

because the file pointer (not the one used for memory allocation) has moved to the end. To read from the file, you have to bring it to the front with the `fseek` function.

Comment: @geyan sorry but you i didn't get you. You can certainly use fseek again (even to move beyond file, but don't do it)

Comment: @geyan: Why would you want to do that? `fseek` is the idiomatic way of doing this, and it works just fine. There's no reason for a *second* variable; that just makes the code more confusing--which one should I be using again??

Comment: What does the last two parameters in the function fseek() mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to seek back to the beginning of the file after you write to it and before you start reading:

```
fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
```

is your first problem. `getc` and `getchar` return `int`s, not a `char`s. Read the man page carefully and change that local to:

```
int c;
```

You're also not resetting the `inFile` stream after the writes. Put something like:

```
fseek(inFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

before you start reading from that stream. (See the man page.)

Lastly, your main signature is not standard. Use:

```
int main(void) { ...
```

Comment: What you have will work, but please form the habit of defining main( ) as int main (int argc, char ** argv ). It will save you tons of grief later.

Comment: Instead of fseek inFile, 0L, SEEK_SET you can also say rewind( inFile ); which (to me, anyway) is easier to remember and clearer to the reader. Such code obeys the rule that, after a write and before a read, you must somehow reposition the file's read pointer.